# cin.get() is not working for char array

Tags: c++

Hello everyone I have made this simple program but there is some problem in taking input book name the program just skip the cin.get() function and then return 0, and I dont know why it's not working although there are no errors. any help would be appreciated. thank you

```
#include<iostream>
 using namespace std;
 struct book
 {
 private:
 int bookid;
 char name[30];
 float price;
 public: 
 input()
 {
    cout<<"\n Enter book ID: ";
    cin>>bookid;
 if(bookid<0)
 {
    bookid = -bookid;
 }
    cout<<"\nEnter book title: ";
    cin.get(name,30); // here is the problem
    cout<<"\nEnter book price: ";
    cin>>price;
 }
 display()
 {
    cout<<"\nBook ID: "<<bookid<<"\nbook title: "<<name<<"\nprice: "<<price;
 }
 };

 int main()
 {
 book b1;
 b1.input();
 b1.display();


 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: What do you mean by not working?

Comment: What's _not working_ specifically? Always post a [MCVE] including all error messages, inputs, expected outputs when asking a question at Stack Overfow.

Comment: when I run it skip the cin.get() function

Comment: You question is a dupe of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction) but since that one uses `getline` I'm hesitant to close it.  I'll let others decide.

Comment: Always provide a [MCVE] including all error messages, input and expected output in your question. Also consider to [take The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.)

Comment: I have also tried using string and getline but same result

Comment: @Waleed See my updated answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making  `name` a `string` rather than a character array, then use `cin >> name;` (for a single-word string) or `cin.getline(name);` (for a multi-word string). You will have to add `#include <string>` to the top of your program.

In general, don't use character arrays in C++ (that's more of a C thing).

---

EDIT:

I think your problem is here:

`cin >> bookid;` will stop when it detects a `'\n'` in the input stream, **and then leave that `\n` in the stream.**  Then, when you call `cin.getline(name);` right after, the first character it will read is the `'\n'`, and so it will immediately return because "it has read a line."  This is a difference between `cin >>` and `cin.getline()`.

So the solution is to replace `cin.getline(name)`; with

```
cin.getline();
cin.getline(name);
```

That way it will get and discard the single `'\n'` (including any other whitespace that may precede the unwanted `'\n'`) before reading the line actually containing the name.

*If you know for a fact that the very next character is `'\n'` rather than some amount of other whitespace followed by a `'\n'`, then you can just do `cin.ignore();` to ignore the very next character, i.e. the `'\n'`.*

Comment: thank you, for your nice explanation, got the concept.

Comment: @Waleed he is not explaining, he is giving an alternative answer.But his question is why cin.get() is ignored.